# Trying to get PHP to find user password in a dictionary wordlist? Code can find generic passwords like Banana123 but BananaC123 will return nothing

Tags: php

The user can enter a password into a POST form and the code will search the wordlist $file for the password. If it finds the password in the wordlist, it will inform the user. This works 90% of the time for generic passwords like Banana123 and Brad101. However, if the user enters a password like BananaK123 the code will return nothing. Is there a way to make the code ignore the letter 'K' in the password BananaK123 so it just searches for Banana123 instead?

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    
  function dictionaryCheck() {
 
    $file = file_get_contents("100k-most-used-passwords-NCSC.txt");
   
    if(isset($_POST['dictionaryCheck'])){
        $password = ($_POST['password']);                         
        $password2 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $password);
        $pos = stristr($file, $password2);

        if ($pos === false) {
            echo "The dictionary word '$password2' was not found";
        } else {
            echo "The dictionary word '$password2' was found ";
            echo " and exists at position $pos";
        }                
           
    }                                            
  }
}
  dictionaryCheck();
```

Comment: In general terms, you're looking to match passwords that are one letter off from the one in the list? The single use case you've presented is very specific and I doubt that's what you had in mind. What about `BananKa123`? `KBanana123`? What about `Banan123`?

Comment: The K makes it a fair bit less guessable. So it is really a problem?

Comment: [levenshtein distance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) might help.

Comment: @El_Vanja yeah, ur right I didn't think about that. Thanks

Comment: Recommend using [`ZXCVBN`](https://github.com/bjeavons/zxcvbn-php) instead of an exact check against this word list, as it will pick up on cases like you're noting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into similar_text(). You may want to reject strings that match a certain similarity.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

This was just to answer your direct question. However, I would not suggest this way. ZXCVBN is a better solution. The reason I am saying this is that you will not be able to tell your users WHY you are rejecting that password. You may cause a lot of frustration.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, we have to code it ourselves so no github functions.

Comment: similar_text is a built-in PHP provided function available since PHP4.